# How to convert output of Z inverse transform into an array in python

Tags: python, inverse-transform

I am using 'lcapy' library in python to calculate inverse Z transform of a given function H(z). The problem is that h(n) output of 'IZT()' looks like a symbolic output for display, and I cannot plot or process it as a typical array or number in python.

One example is when I want to plot h(n) only for a limited numbers of n s, I receive the following error:
*TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'DiscreteTimeDomainExpression'*

That would be great if anyone guide me how I can convert the output of *h=H.IZT()* into a typical number for *n=1*, for instance.
Many thanks for any helps in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Problem is solved by applying 'fval' function on the output of the h(n).